# colCount not working for LegendItem in pyqtgraph with PyQt5 library

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, legend, pyqtgraph

From what I can tell from pyqtgraph documentation at https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/legenditem.html,
I should be able to set the number of columns in the legend either with colCount in the initial function call, or with the method setColCount, but neither seem to work.

The following code adds a legend no problem:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
label = pg.LabelItem(justify='right')
win.addItem(label)
p1 = win.addPlot(row=1, col=0)

legend = pg.LegendItem(offset=(100, 10))
legend.setParentItem(p1.graphicsItem())

plotlines = []

data1 = [n**2 for n in range(100)]
thisline = p1.plot(data1, pen="r")
plotlines.append(thisline)
legend.addItem(plotlines[-1],'Data 1')

data2 = [n for n in range(100)]
thisline = p1.plot(data2, pen='b')
plotlines.append(thisline)
legend.addItem(plotlines[-1],'Data 2')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

However if I try to convert the legend into one with two columns, by adding this line:

```
legend.setColumnCount(2)
```

right after the setParentItem method, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'LegendItem' object has no attribute 'setColumnCount'
```

Which confuses me as I think the documentation tells me it should work.  Can someone explain how I could get two columns and how I'm misreading the documentation?

Update:  With guidance from eyllanesc, found that my version of LegendItem.py did not match the documentation.  Updated to the version currently in  anaconda/packages/pyqtgraph (looks like 0.11.0) and this has the colCount parameter and works as expected.

Comment: How did you install pyqtgraph?

Comment: I'm using anaconda - I can't remember if I installed separately or if it came with the initial package, but if I did install separately it would have been with conda.

Comment: reviewing the pyqtgraph repo I have found that the master branch has the property columnCount but in the develop branch I remove it, it seems that your pyqtgraph belongs to the develop branch

Comment: I'm using anaconda - I believe it came with the package I installed but if it didn't I would have installed with conda.  I just realized I could double click on the LegendItem method to open the .py file - which definitely doesn't have colCount anywhere so that explains why it's causing an error but I still don't understand why there's a reference to it in the pyqtgraph documentation.  The path to the py file is:  AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\LegendItem.py

Comment: The answer is simple: The documentation is outdated.

Comment: Any idea how I could add that functionality in?  Anywhere I might be able to find the previous version that had it as a reference?

Comment: uninstall pyqtgraph using conda, download the repo and install;  `git clone https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph.git` `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem I wrote an ugly fix, taking the code from the current pyqtgraph repo. I added a function:

```
def setColumnCount(legend, columnCount):
    """change the orientation of all items of the legend
    """
    def _addItemToLayout(legend, sample, label):
        col = legend.layout.columnCount()
        row = legend.layout.rowCount()
        if row:
            row -= 1
        nCol = legend.columnCount * 2
        # FIRST ROW FULL
        if col == nCol:
            for col in range(0, nCol, 2):
                # FIND RIGHT COLUMN
                if not legend.layout.itemAt(row, col):
                    break
            if col + 2 == nCol:
                # MAKE NEW ROW
                col = 0
                row += 1
        legend.layout.addItem(sample, row, col)
        legend.layout.addItem(label, row, col + 1)
    
    legend.columnCount = columnCount
    legend.rowCount = int(len(legend.items) / columnCount)
    for i in range(legend.layout.count() - 1, -1, -1):
        legend.layout.removeAt(i)  # clear layout
    for sample, label in legend.items:
        _addItemToLayout(legend, sample, label)
    legend.updateSize()
```

Which you can use with your LegendItem:

```
setColumnCount(legend, 2)
```

Works form me using pyqtgraph-0.11.0-py_0.conda. Note, that this relies on the internal structure of the LegendItem class and might not work with later versions.

To somehow take care for that, I added a try ... except block:

```
try:
    legend.setColumnCount(2)
except AttributeError:
    self.setColumnCount(self.legend, 2)
```